# I was trying to do migrate my work items and iteration history from one Azure DevOps account to another account but I faced the following problem

Tags: devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

I am using Scrum Process on both source and target and when I try to migrate, the following error is thrown. Could anyone help me on this Azure DevOps Migration Tool.

```
[14:02:48 DBG] 1062 Work items received, verifying
[14:02:52 DBG] Loading 1062 Work Items
[14:02:52 DBG] 1/1062 0.09%
[14:03:02 DBG] 28/1062 2.64%
[14:03:12 DBG] 96/1062 9.04%
[14:03:22 DBG] 162/1062 15.25%
[14:03:32 DBG] 229/1062 21.56%
[14:03:42 DBG] 297/1062 27.97%
[14:03:52 DBG] 365/1062 34.37%
[14:04:02 DBG] 427/1062 40.21%
[14:04:12 DBG] 491/1062 46.23%
[14:04:22 DBG] 557/1062 52.45%
[14:04:32 DBG] 620/1062 58.38%
[14:04:42 DBG] 686/1062 64.6%
[14:04:52 DBG] 753/1062 70.9%
[14:05:03 DBG] 821/1062 77.31%
[14:05:13 DBG] 887/1062 83.52%
[14:05:23 DBG] 956/1062 90.02%
[14:05:33 DBG] 1025/1062 96.52%
[14:05:39 DBG] 1062 Work Items loaded
[14:05:39 INF] Replay all revisions of 1062 work items?
[14:05:39 INF] Found target project as Tahses-LMS
[14:05:39 WRN] ValidatingRequiredField: Product Backlog Item does not contain Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId
[14:05:39 WRN] ValidatingRequiredField: Task does not contain Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId
[14:05:39 WRN] ValidatingRequiredField: Epic does not contain Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId
[14:05:39 WRN] ValidatingRequiredField: Feature does not contain Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId
[14:05:39 ERR] Not all work items in scope contain a valid ReflectedWorkItemId Field!
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.InvalidFieldValueException: Not all work items in scope contain a valid ReflectedWorkItemId Field!
[14:05:39 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.InvalidFieldValueException: Not all work items in scope contain a valid ReflectedWorkItemId Field!
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 130
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47
[14:05:39 ERR] WorkItemMigration The Processor MigrationEngine entered the failed state...stopping run
[14:05:39 INF] Application is shutting down...
[14:05:39 DBG] Hosting stopping
[14:05:39 DBG] Exiting with return code: 0
[14:05:39 INF] Terminating: Application forcebly closed.
[14:05:39 INF] Application Ending
[14:05:39 INF] The application ran in 00:03:14.7480477 and finished at 02/05/2022 14:05:39
```

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem. Have you investigated what it's telling you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about this tool, you cannot, you can only use inherited process which you add the ReflectedWorkItemId (string) in the work item types that you want to migrate.

Just as the error message is telling you: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.InvalidFieldValueException: Not all work items in scope contain a valid ReflectedWorkItemId Field!